# Auto populate cell value with dates

Tags: excel-formula

I need to auto populate any two cells in Excel with the 16th of the previous month and the 15th of the current month based on the system date.

Example: Current month is January based on the system date.

So cell "A1" and "A2" need to be populated with 16-DEC-2018 and 15-JAN-2019.

Comment: why VBA?  A simple formula based on TODAY() would do this automatically?

Comment: Scott,Please see example. It should take today's system date's month and populate cell with late month 16th in one cell and this moth 15th in other cell,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use excel formulas like Scott suggested. There's no reason to do this with VBA.

Give cell A1 the formula: `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-1,16)`

Give cell A2 the formula: `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),15)`

If you need the dates in that specific format, set the cells to have a custom format of `dd-mmm-yyyy`

Comment: hey , yes it works. Thanks to both Josh and Scott. I was not aware of this formula

Comment: @arvindrajnagasamy if this answered your question, please do not forget to mark it as the accepted answer.